# git exclude everything in folder except a subdirectory

Tags: node.js, git

I am working on a node js project and I am creating a node module that for now want have it added to the project I am working on. So in my gitignore I put the following but it did not work

```
node_modules/*
!node_modules/zephyr-rest
```

The zephyr-rest is a directory, so I want just that directory and its files to be saved. I do not want any other sub directory under node_modules to be versioned. Thanks

Comment: `!node_modules/zephyr-rest/` maybe?

Comment: This post might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533050/gitignore-exclude-folder-but-include-specific-subfolder

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this, worked for me.

```
node_modules/*
!node_modules/zephyr-rest/
```

After `git status` it will show like this

```
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

  node_modules/
```

Don't worry because `git status` just tells the top-most untracked folder as `untracked` not every subfolder, so this tells there is an untracked folder `node_modules`. Doing `git add node_modules` should add just `node_modules/zephyr-rest/`

Comment: Here is what git status shows me after the change 

On branch master
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

 modified:   .gitignore
 modified:   routes/index.js

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

 node_modules/

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

Comment: so it should be working. If you are getting confused it's showing `node_modules` try to add it will add just `zephyr-rest` folder.